# Permit closing window with unsaved changes using vim setting

Tags: buffers, save, quit

I wrote a plugin that executes a slow shell script and asynchronously shows the stdout in a popup (split) window. When I try to close my session while the popup is open, I get the message

```
Save changes to "popup.log"?
[Y]es, (N)o, (C)ancel
```

How can I automatically reject changes to this temporary buffer without rejecting changes to the files I am actually editing (as would happen with `:qa!`)?

Is there some buffer-local option I can set that allows the buffer to changes but specifies "this is a temporary buffer, but never ever ask me to save changes"? Seems like lots of vim plugins do this (tagbar, NERDtree, etc.) but I don't know how.

Comment: `setlocal buftype=nofile noswapfile`. See `:h special-buffers`.

Comment: @Matt Thanks! Could you post this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some buffer-local option I can set that allows the buffer to changes but specifies "this is a temporary buffer, but never ever ask me to save changes"?

The most essential one is `buftype=nofile`. Also, `:h special-buffers` recommends using `noswapfile` (nowadays often switched off globally) and `bufhidden=hide` (so a buffer can be reused after `:quit`-ting the window; but note that `ZQ` and `:quit!` still drop it completely). As following these recommendations does not seem to hurt, you can do

```
setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile
```